# How to get gwt jars version information if it is not available in manifest file?

Tags: java, gwt, jar

I have gwt-user.jar and gwt-dev.jar in my application. I want to know which version of gwt jar is used in my application. I looked into the Manifest.mf file inside jar file but there is no version info available there. So, is there any other way to know the version for this jar files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT provides the information in several ways:

- `gwt-dev.jar` contains a `com/google/gwt/dev/About.properties`
- you can launch the `gwt-dev.jar` (`java -jar gwt-dev.jar`, or `java -cp gwt-dev.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler`, and it'll give you the version information)
- the version is also available into the generated JS, and/or accessible from client code using `GWT.getVersion()`

Comment: Thanks, I got the version for gwt-dev.jar from About.properties file but it is not available for gwt-user.jar....how to get version info for gwt-user.jar file ?

Comment: They should come from the same GWT version or you take the risk of breaking your compilation. This is why the version is not included in gwt-user.